# 404 page when using params in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the end of the file I've

```
app.use(function(req,res){
 res.render('404.jade');
});
```

and that works for www.website/wrongpath, but in my

```
app.get('/path/:id', function(req, res){}
```

it doesn't work at all and it breaks the nodeserver when you write a bad id like /path/23187123.
I've tried doing something like:

```
function checkifexists(){
  var checktime = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?', [globalid], function(err, results, rows){
    if(results.length == 0){
      //console.log("0");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
} 

if(checkifexists()){return;}
```

To check if the id exists and then cancel the request, but that doesn't work either. How can I get it to work with the 404 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next()` within your route when it does not know to handle a particular request. In your case, if there are no records on `table` table, it should pass the request to the next handler that matches this request, which will probably be your `404`.

```
app.get('/path/:id', function(req, res, next){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?', [globalid], function(err, results, rows){
    if(results.length == 0){
      next();
      return;
    }

    //do something with rows
    //res.render('view.jade')
  });
}
```

Comment: Im getting `TypeError: next is not a function` even with it in `app.get('/path/:id', function(req, res, next){`

Comment: You're right, I've forget to add `next` as the third parameter. But it should  be working with it. What's your express version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next()` to pass the handling of the request to other middleware:

```
app.get('/path/:id', function(req, res, next){

//say if id is too big, don't handle it in this controller
if(req.params.id > 10000) {
  next();
  return;
}

//other code
})
//- so we go further down

//here comes the error display
app.use(function(req,res){
 res.render('404.jade');
});
```